# How is it better to send data using Dapper in c# to PL/SQL scripts variables of RECORD type

Tags: c#, plsql, dapper

I have a PL/SQL procedure that using 3 variables of `RECORD` type as parameters, which i have to fill with my data (from c# application) to execute a procedure.

1st i've tried to build the same structure with this records via c# and pass as a parameter via Dapper, but it's not working since dapper works only with scalar data types.

Then i've tried to pass my data as arrays and to map them inside the procedure, but RECORD type can't accept sets of data like `a.NAME := ('aaaaaa','sdasd');` it works only this way:

```
a.NAME(1) := 'aaaaaa';
a.NAME(2) := 'sdasd';
```

The only thing that i have on my mind now is to generate such strings in the procedure text, but i'm feeling like there should be a better way. What am doing wrong?

P.S. i can't change the script that needs to be running after all, so i can't change the data type it accepts.

Update:
To make it easier, let's say, i've decided to make an example:

We have 2 custom types

```
TYPE A_REC IS RECORD (NAME dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table);
TYPE B_REC IS RECORD (NAME dbms_sql.Varchar2_Table
                         , ID dbms_sql.Number_Table);
```

and a procedure, which might be used something like

```
declare
a c_pck.a_rec;
b c_pck.b_rec;
begin

a.NAME(1) := 'aaaaa';
b.NAME(1) := 'sssss';
b.NAME(2) := 'ddddd';
b.ID(1) := 111;
b.ID(2) := 222;


c_pck.pr(a => a, b => b);
end;
```

How can i run this procedure via Dapper?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this will work for PL\SQL, however you can pass in `SQL` Table Value Parameters into a stored procedure that you call from Dapper. `RECORD` types sound like the same thing so it may work.

You need to use a `DataTable` to construct your `RECORD`. The order of the columns that you define must match the same order that they appear in your database.

From the below link:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("AUDIT_PK", typeof (long));
dt.Columns.Add("MESSAGE", typeof (string));
dt.Columns.Add("SUCCESS", typeof (bool));
dt.Rows.Add(1, "EHLO", null);

using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial  Catalog=Scratch;Integrated Security=true"))
{
    conn.Open();
    conn.Execute("TestOne", new {TVP =   dt.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.AUDITRECORD")}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
}
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/835519/Passing-Table-Valued-Parameters-with-Dapper

Comment: getting `System.ArgumentException: value out of range` in `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.set_Value(Object value)` in `Dapper.TableValuedParameter.Set(IDbDataParameter parameter, DataTable table, String typeName)` etc this way

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle two separate things here.

1. Instruct the Oracle driver about your custom data types

Here, you're going to need a fair amount of boilerplate.
You have to write mapping code for your UDTs, using the `IOracleCustomType` interface. [Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featUDTs.htm#ODPNT379) the official documentation. [This guide](http://www.uchithar.net/2014/05/odp-dot-net-usage-and-samples-part-ii.html) seems like a good resource.

2. Instruct Dapper about your custom data types

Dapper has a hard-coded list of .NET types mapped to DbTypes.
You can add to this list, but only to the generic DbTypes.
To use database specific functionality, your parameter must implement
    `SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter` (this is how the Table-valued
    stuff for SQL server works). In your `AddParameter` implementation, you can manually construct an `OracleParameter` and set the UDT typename correctly.
The return value should be handled just fine by Dapper, since this is just mapping a result set like

Comment: sounds interesting, but i'm using Oracle, not PG
will look for something like this

Comment: That was me completely mis-reading PL/SQL as PLPGSQL. Sorry about that :-)

Comment: Anyway, the dapper interface to control how you create the parameter will be the same. Then I think you have to look at the `OracleCustomTypeMapping` attribute to instruct Oracle about your data.

Comment: Wanted to do some quick tests on an oracle development base I have access to, but unfortunately, "ODP.NET, Managed Driver does not support UDTs and .NET Custom Types". I'm not polluting my visual studio with the unmanaged stuff, sorry :)