# How to use DataTable (or similar) with Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle, dapper, .net-core-2.0, devart

I've recently been dealing with some performance problems and am trying to figure out how to exponentially increase the performance of some calls to an Oracle DB.

Technologies:

- .NET Core 2
- Oracle DB
- Dapper (optional)
- [Devart](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Devart.Data.Oracle/9.5.454) (optional)
- [OracleManaged](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/2.12.0-beta2) (optional, beta)

I am familiar with the use of `DataTable` and Table-Valued Parameters for Dapper and SQL Server and wish to replicate that with the technologies above. I have not yet been able to reproduce the solution below to work with Devart nor OracleManaged:

> The code below is not what I'm running... It's a paraphrased example. I just need something that works with Oracle to pass a DataTable or array of objects to be used in a query/insert.

SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE MyCustomerInfo AS TABLE
(
    Id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    --Name NVARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    --...
);
```

C# for SQL Server:

```
const string getCustomersSql = @"
    SELECT
        c.Id,
        --c.Name
        --...
    FROM @myCustomers mc
    LEFT JOIN Customers c
        ON c.Id = mc.Id";

var myCustomers = new DataTable();
myCustomers.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(long));
//...

myCustomers.Rows.Add(1);
myCustomers.Rows.Add(2);

var customers = await sqlDbConnection.QueryAsync<Customer>(getCustomersSql, new { myCustomers = myCustomers.AsTableValuedParameter("MyCustomerInfo") });
```

Oracle DB (PL/SQL):

```
CREATE TYPE MY_CUSTOMER_INFO AS OBJECT
(
    ID BIGINT,
    --NAME VARCHAR2(32),
    --...
);

CREATE TYPE MY_CUSTOMER_INFO_ARRAY AS TABLE OF MY_CUSTOMER_INFO;
```

**C# for Oracle DB:**

I made a similar approach as with SQL Server but with both Devart and OracleManaged and neither worked. I also [very-unhappily] tried using `OracleCommand` and `OracleParameter` directly - again with both Devart and OracleManaged - to no avail.

My results with Devart seem to indicate that the functionality is intentionally prevented. My results with OracleManaged seem to indicate that it hasn't been implemented yet, which isn't surprising since it's beta (supposedly released Q3 this year).

My next approach may be to use associated arrays (in which I have very little experience or desire to learn) with Devart. At this point I'm just probing for something that will work with similar performance gains...

**EDIT**: Using an array-per-parameter approach is possible but is awfully inconvenient as large classes end up with 12+ arrays. I'd like an alternative to this approach.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739027/how-is-it-better-to-send-data-using-dapper-in-c-sharp-to-pl-sql-scripts-variable/49740534#49740534? Even if it's not, I think my answer might be good to read :)

Comment: Also, mapping between oracle UDTs and .NET types is not supported for the ODP.NET managed driver. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featUDTs.htm#ODPNT379

Comment: Mapping what exactly? The DataTable to MY_CUSTOMER_INFO_ARRAY? I don't need to map the output.

Comment: Yes, this mapping has to happen in the .NET driver, and Oracle specifically says in the page I linked that custom mapping of .NET types to user data types is not supported in the ODP.NET managed driver.

You're talking of mapping a DataTable to a UDT, and not a custom class - I can't find anything specifically about that in the documentation, maybe that's doable.

Comment: Anyway, to make it work via Dapper you have to wrap the parameter in your custom ICustomQueryParameter. The `TableValuedParameter` of dapper is only implemented for SQL server - https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper/TableValuedParameter.cs

Comment: I don't need to stick to using Dapper, my question is mostly how to accomplish using DataTable with Oracle. As I mentioned, I have also tried using `OracleCommand` directly (Dapper is not relevant at that point). I will continue looking into using type mappings or associative arrays for now.

Comment: You can check NReco.Data which has RecordSet structure which can be used as Table-Valued Parameter for SQL Server: https://github.com/nreco/data/wiki/RecordSet#use-recordset-as-table-valued-parameter-for-sql-server-stored-procedure , maybe it will work for OracleManaged too

Comment: I dislike "well you could just..." comments. They are not answers. Please provide working examples with whatever technology you can to show that passing large data sets to an Oracle DB is possible without using the array-per-parameter approach.

Answer (score 1):

@Kody this post is a little old, so this probably won't help you but for others this may help.  Although I don't know of any way to use a datatable/UDT with the Managed Oracle Client, if you strictly just want to reduce the number of round trips to the DB and perform a bunch of inserts/deletes/updates with one call to the DB you could try this approach:

```
using (var dbConn = ManagedOracleHelper.GetConnection())
{
    dbConn.Open();
    var cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
    var udtList = GetUDTList(); // A dummy method to get a collection of Model 
                                // objects you want to use for the bulk operation.
                                // This could be a dataset too, you would just need
                                // to change the code within the for-loop to iterate
                                // over rows and access the columns by name.

    var firstNameArr = new string[udtList.Count];
    var lastNameArr  = new string[udtList.Count];
    var emailArr     = new string[udtList.Count];

    for (var i = 0; i < udtList.Count; i++)
    {
        firstNameArr[i] = udtList[i].FirstName;
        lastNameArr[i]  = udtList[i].LastName;
        emailArr[i]     = udtList[i].Email;
    }

    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL)
                        VALUES(:FirstName, :LastName, :Email)";;
    cmd.BindByName  = true;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("FirstName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("LastName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Email", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);

    cmd.ArrayBindCount = udtList.Count;

    cmd.Parameters["FirstName"].Value = firstNameArr;
    cmd.Parameters["LastName"].Value  = lastNameArr;
    cmd.Parameters["Email"].Value     = emailArr;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Not sure how performant this would be if you were inserting/updating hundreds of millions of records, but I have tested this with inserting 80K records and my import feature went from taking multiple minutes (previously someone coded this as a simple loop calling an insert for each record) down to a few seconds.  I don't have exact numbers because once the import time went down by almost 2 orders of magnitude, I was happy enough to move on with other things.

Comment: This is the associative array approach. It's similar to what I ended up doing but it's pretty inconvenient. To do vast insertions to SQL Server, you basically just pass the list object straight to the SQL query and it runs incredibly fast. Fortunately, I don't have to hit Oracle DB directly anymore. It wasn't the answer I was looking for, but thanks anyways.

Comment: Yah, it boggles my mind that anyone willingly uses Oracle.  I miss my SQL server days.  Perhaps this might help someone else with a similar frustration as us ;-)